# Standard production setup for php

Tags: php, apache, lamp, production-environment, chmod

Background
I've recently setup a php based site on a host I have root access to. I've installed a lamp setup based on the guides at linode.com, and I'm now wondering what's to be done about php file permissions, directory permissions, and which users should run which processes in which groups.

In particular I'd like an answer to the question "How should a standard php web site be configured with respect to ACLs, ownership and produciton ids?"

Currently any directory listing returns the following:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root   70 Nov  8 17:17 index.php
```

i.e. `root` owner, `root` group, mode `644` / `uw & ar`. ([edit] Which is not how it should be since files should not be created using root - part of the reason for this question)

Running `ps -auxww` I see the Apache web server runs as a user called `www-data`, so I can presume that php will run as that same user (presumably it's a child process which will inherit the same user).

Would it be wrong for me to set `chmod 640` on all files, and set myself (user `bob`) as the owner, create a group called `productionIDs` containing the `www-data` user, set group on the file to be `productionIDs`?

Seems to me this would be more secure in terms of least privilege; who else is there other than myself and the web server? Only I need to write the files, and the web server only needs to read. Nobody else needs to do anything.

My setup doesn't handle the case where there are multiple developers, but I'm not sure what this case should look like.

So are there any risks with `640` owner me, group web server group? If so, is the corresponding directory `750` safe too?

If not, why don't more people use this configuration?

[update] Under *try it and see* theory, it works. So the question now includes a "what does this configuration not allow/what are the disadvantages of this configuration" aspect.

Comment: What you ask depends a lot of how the system works. What could be said straight away is that you should not create PHP files as root. Period. And I only comment that for security sake. To actually answer your question would require writing a book which is not a good way to ask btw.

Comment: The question asks you to describe an ideal configuration of users + groups + file permissions in order to determine an ideal production setup. It does not cover how the files got there, and it would be all the same if the files had magically appeared under somebody else's (non-root) user who was about to have their privileges revoked. The question of "what should the future setup look like" remains unchanged. If it depends on anything, then I should have included that in the question and you should ask for it in your answer.

Comment: Well, if you are concerned about a systems configuration issue, than this is off-topic here. You might want to ask that over at superuser or probably better serverfault.

Comment: The context is php, the superuser is irrelevant for the reasons I gave earlier, which for completeness I now give again: It would be all the same if the files in question had been created by another non-superuser who was being revoked.

Comment: It remains. You still are concerned only about what does mode 640 mean (`urw & gr`) and what does 750 mean (`urwx & grx`). Reducing it to that point I do first of all see a configuration question here. This heavily depends how the webserver is configured and how PHP is invoked and based on that configuration what the PHP script is permitted or allowed with system resources. Also I can not follow what you write in your question, the part about "Why don't do others do it that way". It looks more like a common setup to me - not an uncommon one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your files should definitely not be owned by root:root. Start with a username and generic group for all ownership.

While it is initially true that the web server user will only need read/execute access to your files there are certainly cases where that user might need write access to a specific folder for uploads or application logs, etc.

So our typical setup for a PHP application is 644 on the files (640 is fine, too) and 755 for the folders (750 will also work). Note we leave the files readable by everyone for a couple of reasons. First, it allows other users to audit code on a server without having the ability to modify it. Second, we only have developer users on the production hosting server so anyone with an account already has the trust level to see all the code. That situation might vary in another setting.

Regarding your question of using the web server group as the group owner, we usually do not do that. While you could certainly use that group, we like to leave all the system-installed groups alone and create a specific group for the application files. Then we just add the web server user to the new group.

Comment: Thanks, so OWNER should be the human user who created it, and the www-data user should be added to a group (say php-readers) and php-readers should be GROUP on the file. The only reason to set 0 for others is if you have dirty secrets in your code you don't want other developers to see.

Comment: @Dan: For the group not necessarily. But as written *that* depends on server configuration and your needs.

Comment: @Dan, yes, that's the way we do it. And yes, there have been times to set 0 for others for exactly the reason you mentioned! ;)